# how to use find -exec without lots of escaping

Tags: bash

I often use `find` to run the same script on a bunch of files. So for example if I want to run `process.py` on all the `.png` files in `dir`, I would do:

```
find dir -name '*.png' -execdir process.py \{\} \;
```

The picket fence thing in the end is annoying, any way around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your keyboard layout, `"` might be more convenient to use than `'` or `\`. The `{}` does not need escaping, as far as the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which) Stack Exchange site knows. Nobody could identify a shell that would need `{}` escaped, and the examples in the man page do not escape the braces.

```
find dir -name "*.png" -execdir process.py {} ";"
```

Jonathan Leffler has a solution with + in the end, which is not identical in semantics, but often usable.

Comment: This addresses the point. I like [Jonathan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10320437/915501) but I didn't want to change the effect, just to avoid typing all the \. At least this is two less.

Comment: not sure I understand this: `Nowbody could tell a shell, where it would need maskings, while it is written in the man page.` The [man page examples](http://ss64.com/bash/find.html#examples) do indeed show `'{}'`, but this is apparently not required by bash (I checked).

Comment: @Shep: [Here is the U&L diskussion about {}](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which) started by me.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
find dir -name '*.png' -execdir process.py {} +
```

The `{}` don't need escaping; they only have special meaning to the shell in rather limited circumstances.  (In particular, `echo {}` echoes the braces, whereas `echo {a,b,c}` echoes `a b c`.) The `+` does not need escaping either.  It tells `find` to 'play at being `xargs`'.  That is, it will run the command with as many file names as it reasonably can for each execution.

Note that using `-exec` or `-execdir` automatically and comprehensively deals with the problem of spaces (and other awkward characters — newlines, backspaces, form feeds, anyone?) in file names.  Piping names with `-print` into `xargs` runs foul of problems here.  GNU `find` plus GNU `xargs` provides the `-print0` option to `find` and the `-0` option to `xargs` to get around issues with odd characters in file names.

If you must execute the script once per file, then you need an escaped semi-colon at the end; there is no easy way around that (unless you count: `SC=";"; find ... {} $SC`, which I don't).

The only issue I see is the `-execdir` which runs the script in the sub-directory.  You'll have to check that it behaves sanely when there are different files in different directories, and you'll need to be sure that `{}` translates to 'the file name relative to the directory it is found in' when used with `-execdir` (as otherwise, the file won't be locatable via the name that is given to the script, in general).  All of this should 'just work' as the options wouldn't be meaningfully usable if they didn't.

Personally, I'd rather use just plain `-exec`, but there's probably a good reason why you chose `-execdir`.

Comment: Find itself takes care, that the files it finds are passed correctly to your script, whether you use -exec or -execdir - no need to worry. It is just sometimes useful to perform a program in the directory where the file is - renaming, reading some config information, ... .

Comment: To be usable, it pretty much has to do that.  I've not used `-execdir` (I had to go check the man page to see what it did).  I can see it might be a little bit helpful occasionally, but my scripting style wouldn't be affected by `-exec` vs `-execdir` for essentially any circumstance I can think of.

Comment: sorry for the contrived example, but @userunknown addresses the problem: the directory where `process.py` resides has a lot more than just the file it finds, so the relative paths are important.

Answer (score 0):

you can single quote '{}' ';' instead, but you would have to somehow prevent shell itself from interpreting these characters. xargs will work as well if the number of found is small.

Comment: It's funny that you say "`xargs` will work as well if the number of files found is small", since the whole point of `xargs` is that it will work if the number of files found is enormous.  It splits the files into manageable groups and executes the command for each group.